# "Visualization" tag is undefined

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [visualization](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization) tag has been applied to software related questions as well as questions involving light.  Given that we already have a [software](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) tag, all software-related visualization questions are covered by that.  The other two questions that use [visualization](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization) for non-software reasons could work though I would personally like to see these two questions be tagged with something along the lines of  [light](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light) or [electromagnetic-spectrum](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetic-spectrum) or [electromagnetic-radiation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetic-radiation).

Comment: If you do a `[tag:visualization]` it renders and gives a link to the tag.  Instant magic.

Comment: Or we also have @Manish :)

Comment: @jonsca HOLY MOTHER WHAT KIND OF WITCHCRAFT IS THIS?!

Comment: I just retagged everything under [tag:visualization]. I have no points for that tag, so I can't propose a synonym. Otherwise, it's dead.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison The tag being dead is a good thing, it has/had no real purpose in the first place. I often just kill tags, that I believe have already a better equivalent or won't even get ten questions in the long run. Sometimes it's best to do that quietly ;)

Comment: I have marked this as status-completed as was suggested, but usually I reserve that for stuff that we as mods do.

Comment: @jonsca So for reference, do you just need to clear all the questions out of a tag and it'll get removed by the system? If so, it might be helpful to have that as documentation (or a meta Q/A) somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, I'd delete "visualization" for now. I would certainly use it in a [software](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) context, and the other two questions probably should use [electromagnetic-radiation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetic-radiation).

(Personally, I'd remove "visualization" from the [invisible ink](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16189/best-invisible-ink-for-clothing) question.)

**Update**

I just edited everything under [visualization](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization) so there are no more questions there.

Comment: Well that goal is only 2000 rep points away. That could be done in 10 days time. I'd bet your university and students will be quite understanding when you explain to them why you immediately need 10 days off :)

Comment: Oh no, I have access to the moderator tools now, but I haven't had a chance to figure out how to delete the tag. At the least, it's empty.

Comment: Sorry, confused "moderator tools" with "trusted user" privileges. But have you read [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it)? Apparently, you have done exactly what is necessary to get rid of an unwanted tag by removing the tag from all questions. It already seems to have been removed from the system - at least it doesn't show up anymore under "tags". But if it comes up regularly it might be a good idea to declare it as a synonym for [tag:software].

Comment: I was just going editing some questions, and noticed that the electromagnetic-radiation tag was unused/undefined. Is there a reason for this? Simply searching "photon" brings up many questions that could fall under this tag.