# Visualization tag has reappeared - should we burninate it?

Tags: discussion, tags

[visualization](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization) reappeared today. It was previously deleted after [this](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/498/visualization-tag-is-undefined) meta discussion. Should we remove it again, or perhaps merge it with [software](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[My reaction after seeing this meta post](http://cdn.24.co.za/files/Cms/General/d/2464/f2f06ae5ff9a48108a3f92621b5f88b8.gif); [my ultimate advice](http://38.media.tumblr.com/9f2de0195a0fbead8e73c80d88f72261/tumblr_inline_mrlh1x5Dtw1qz4rgp.gif)

[visualization](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization) is gone, burnt to a crisp, destiny, history, whatever you may wish to call it.

It was only applied to one question, seemed kinda meta kinda legit there. I removed it. For one single question, it seemed kinda nice, but as found out before, it does a very vague job as a tag. Next time you saw an undead tag rising again, which means a tag which has been decided to be burninated came back to life, please delete it yourself, before it gets misused more.

[image]

**Case closed.**